# |Node.JS| Whenever I get params.id, I get jumbotron.css

Tags: node.js, parameters

So first of all here is my code

```
router
.get('/find/:_id',(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params._id;
    console.log(id);
    if(id !== 'jumbotron.css'){
    Doc.findById(id)
    .then((doc)=>{
        res.render('table/content',{
            title: doc.subject,
            docs: doc
        })
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    }
});
```

This is the output

```
enterthe server running on 3000
Connected successfully to mongodb
5b00373bbea0a253106e0930
jumbotron.css
```

so whenever I make a GET req using that Id, two items are printed,
first one is id and the second one is 'jumbotron.css',
I have no idea where I am getting jumbotron.css as req.params.id.
This would not let me get into that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `table/content` HTML, you probably have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jumbotron.css">
```

Instead of `href="/jumbotron.css"` or `href="/path/to/css/jumbotron.css"`

And since it's relative to the current URL it is performing a request to:

`/find/jumbotron.css`

That's why you're getting a second request with `id === 'jumbotron.css'`